# Prove that $\left(\int_0^t f(x)g(x)dx\right)^2 \leq \left(\int_0^t f(x)^2 dx\right) \left(\int_0^t g(x)^2 dx\right).$

Tags: inequality

Using the fact that $\int_0^t [f(x)+\lambda g(x)]^2 dx \geq 0, $ prove that:

> $$\left(\int_0^t f(x)g(x)dx\right)^2 \leq \left(\int_0^t f(x)^2
>  dx\right) \left(\int_0^t g(x)^2 dx\right).$$

I tried expanding $[f(x)+\lambda g(x)]^2$ but it didn't seem to get me anywhere.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#L2 may be of some help too.

Answer (score 4):

When you integrate the expression $(f+\lambda g)^2$ you obtain a quadratic polynomial with respect to $\lambda$. On the other hand, thi polynomial is non-negative, therefore its discriminant is non-positive, which implies the desired inequality.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** if
$$
\forall \lambda :a\lambda^2 + 2b\lambda + c \ge 0
$$then the discriminant:
$$
b^2 - 4ac
$$
applies (to prove roots).

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have mis-typed the integral limits. They'd most likely be, *t* (upper) and *o* (lower)

Here's what i came to with a near enough identical question since, not enough information was provided.

**Step 1** Expand the function, $\left[f(x)-\lambda g(x)\right]^2\geq0$;

=$g(x)^2\lambda^2-2f(x)g(x)\lambda+f(x)^2$

**Step 2** Integrate the expansion product to verify that *λ* satisfies the quadratic;

=$\left(\int_{a}^{b}g\left[\left(x\right)\right]^{2}dx\right)\lambda^{2}-2\left(\int_{a}^{b}f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)dx\right)\lambda+\int_{a}^{b}f\left[\left(x\right)\right]^{2}dx\geq0$

- *a* and *b* are constants and *λ* can take any real value.

**Note that the function as it stands is classed as, *"strictly non-negative"*. This is key information when going about validating or proving roots/inequalities.**

**Step 3** Proving the inequality;

$\left(\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx\right)^2\leq\left(\int_a^b\left[f(x)\right]^2dx\right).\left(\int_a^b\left[g(x)\right]^2dx\right)$

We produced a "strictly non-negative" quadratic in *λ*, for **step 1** so, it's discriminant will definitively be, $(b^2 - 4ac)$. The inequality when re-arranged contradicts the validity of that statement. Rearranging the inequality gives us;

$0\geq\left(\int_a^b\left[(x)\right]^2dx\right).\left(\int_a^b\left[g(x)\right]^2dx\right)-\left(\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx\right)^2$

Then applying the coefficients derived from **step 1** set; a = 1; b = -2; c = 1. Knowing this we can substitute them them back into the inequality and the find discriminant to prove the origin of the roots.

i.e. 
$(-2)^2-4(1)(1)=0$

Despite this conclusion, *λ* can take any "real" value so, the discriminant must be either negative or equal to zero, due to that variable. Henceforth;

=$\left(-2\left(\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx\right)\right)^2-4\left(\int_a^bf(x)^2dx\right).\left(\int_a^bg(x)^2dx\right)\geq0$

P.s. I hope that I helped!